# Typescript destructure both internal prop of object and object

Tags: typescript

I have a code like that:

```
const { person: { name, age }, house: { height } } = myObject;

// Works
console.log(name);

// Does not work
console.log(person);
```

The problem is that I want to have both a variable `name`, internal of person and a variable `person`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, in the code, person must be specified two times:

```
const { person, person: { name, age }, house: { height } } = myObject;

// Works
console.log(name);

// Does not work
console.log(person);
```

This seems to work